# Can someone steal my code from github and publish my app?

Tags: github

If my entire project is stored in a public github repo what's to stop people from downloading it and publishing it on Google play before I do?

I want to use github to keep track of changes in a group Android project, I was told an active account would also benefit future employment, and make it public to help other students. But what if I wanted to eventually publish it to Google play? See the above question.

I'm new to software development.

Comment: Have a look at [BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/) if you want a remote private git repo.

Comment: You are right if your code is public and people can access it, it can be stolen...now will people actually do that...I'd say morally speaking likely not (at least not completely steal it line for line and call it their own if they're concious of how that is stealing even though it's opensource...but then again it isn't since it _would_ be opensource) . But some people might, so it's just a risk you'd have to take unless you make it private.

Comment: @JoëlSalamin -  Not only **BitBucket** can have remote private repositories, **GitHub** can also have it.

Comment: @WebDeveloper Today, it's true. I posted my comment in 2015, at this time GitHub wasn't offering private repo in the FREE price tier ;-)
It has been introduced in 2019: https://github.blog/2019-01-07-new-year-new-github/

Answer (score 15):

If you find your code online somewhere which you did not permit or without your license, you can submit a DMCA claim. [Here is Google Play's takedown form](https://support.google.com/legal/troubleshooter/1114905) and [GitHub's DMCA guide](https://help.github.com/articles/guide-to-submitting-a-dmca-takedown-notice/).

Comment: Does this only apply to **Apps** and **Google Play** or does it also apply to a **website**?

Answer (score 5):

If you want to keep your code in a private repository, try [BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/), it's a private code repository and free up to five users.

Comment: I believe the OP was also concerned with maintaining "an active GitHub account ... [to] benefit future improvement", and storing code in a private repository doesn't help that goal.

Comment: Keep in mind that 'private' repos, be they GitHub or BitBucket are not encrypted on the servers. MS did not pay 3.5B for GitHub's crappy workflow (Torvalds' words, not mine). GitHub repos are actually stored clear on AWS servers. You can use `git-crypt` to encrypt both public and 'private' GitHub repos on the server. Curious that encryption is not part of the standard, but Torvalds views security as extraneous.

Answer (score 4):

The meaning of a public github repository is specified by github as the following:

Public Repositories can be viewed and cloned by anyone. Choose this if your repository:

is an open source project
should be easy for other members to fork and contribute back their modifications.

I would be a better option to choose private repository(paid on) to keep your code safe.

Yes, you have the option Transfer ownership so you can transfer you code to your future employer using github. Hope it helps you. Let me know if you need any further information,

Transfer this repo to another user or to an organization where you have admin rights.

Answer (score 2):

> If my entire project is stored in a public github repo what's to stop people from downloading it and publishing it on google play before I do?

In theory, nothing.

In practice, few people are going to run across your repository, unless you promote it (e.g., publish links to it). There are **many** repositories in GitHub.

Comment: Well, not always. I published something on GitHub, it became quite popular for some reason, and now someone has published it to Google play. Doubly annoying since it is now an old, seriously broken version on Google play..

Comment: @JonasCz -  See above answer; you can file a **DMCA  claim**.

Answer (score 0):

Any opensource project (such as a public github repo) needs to declare a [software license](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_license#Free_and_open-source_software_licenses). In the case of github, failing to do so implies a default MIT license to any fork (clone), which gives away most rights except attribution.

GPL licenses are viral, meaning any tier in a system that contains GPL code belongs to that GPL. All published code and changes *must* be published back up to the original repo. This seems more suited to your repo. That would include pull requests required to license an appclone, which you could block.

Google will pull any app that clearly violates a license, and right quickly too, since they have some liability to do so. Also, developers have been known to globally broadcast their displeasure when violated.

The boilerplate  license types are fairly clear and bullet-proof, as long as you don't need to change them - for that you should seek legal counsel.

Most corporations stay away from anything not clearly licensed as MIT or weaker. You can get fired for pulling GPL code into (compromising the ownership of) a proprietary codebase. GPL is for educational and partnership arrangements.

So there is obviously a clear trade-off between repo license strength and number of active contributors. An unconditional license can attract contributors, a conditional license can orphan the repo. Business is about relationships.

Answer (score 0):

GitHub has created a nice website to help people decide on a license: https://choosealicense.com/

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use a private repo. You can set anyone as a contributor with write access.

Comment: That solution doesn't work. we just had our private repo stolen through a 3rd party Oauth key databreach and cloned into a public repo exposing all our code to the world. That 3rd party had our Github access by our permission and got hacked. You cannot prevent this from happening just by having your repo private.